# dart sizeof operator or how to find out class instance size in memory

Tags: dart, sizeof

Does Dart have an equivalent to the "sizeof" operator? Or, how can I find out how many bytes a class instance is using in memory?

Answer (score 4):

There's no `sizeof` operator in dart.